# How to update draft version name in Google Play Console?

Tags: continuous-integration, google-play, google-play-console, fastlane

I set up a ci for Google play console. It downloads .aab to internal testing as draft.
The script I use is similiar to this one:

```
fastlane supply --package_name "$PACKAGE_NAME" --aab "$PLAYER_PATH"  --json_key_data "$KEY_WITH_NEWLINES" --release-status draft --track internal
```

It working OK. .aab uploads to Google Play Console. I can see draft release in internal
testing track. On first uploading draft release takes its name from .aab. When I upload another bundle with another version name (and code) it's name stays the same.

I can update draft release name if I delete it and create it again or push it to prod or another tracks (kinda the same. In all these cases draft release will be moved/deleted from internal track).

I other words, I want draft release bundle name to be updated when I update bundle.
For example:
first release had name `alpha-1.0.1` and it to be updated to `alpha-1.0.2` when I upload new bundle with new version name.

Thank you.

- may be there is a way to delete this draft in ci script? (before uploading)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggtLt.png)